# Updating IP addresses in Apache Ambari

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I am running an Ambari installation (1.7.0) on [HDP](http://hortonworks.com/) (2.2.0.0-2041).  After rebooting one of the machines, the internal IP address changed.  This means that Ambari can't find it.  (We're running on AWS EC2, so the hostnames have the form ip-x-x-x-x.)

How do I inform Ambari of the new ip address?  The only option I've found so far is to add a new host, but as I understand this will wipe the machine clean.

Comment: I have also tried adding the a line in the hosts file of the form:

new.i.p.address    old-fully-qualified-domain-name

but this doesn't work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This great blog post helped us:
http://www.swiss-scalability.com/2015/01/rename-host-in-ambari-170.html

Basically you will need to log into Ambari's database.  (Not the GUI, the actual backend database).  It's best to read the blog post in its entirety, but I am appending the important secret sauce that actually makes things happen.

If you're on mysql:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; 
BEGIN;
UPDATE ambari.clusterhostmapping set host_name = '${new-name}' WHERE host_name = '${old-name}';
UPDATE ambari.configgrouphostmapping set host_name = '${new-name}' WHERE host_name = '${old-name}';
UPDATE ambari.host_role_command set host_name = '${new-name}' WHERE host_name = '${old-name}';
UPDATE ambari.hostcomponentdesiredstate set host_name = '${new-name}' WHERE host_name = '${old-name}';
UPDATE ambari.hostcomponentstate set host_name = '${new-name}' WHERE host_name = '${old-name}';
UPDATE ambari.hostconfigmapping set host_name = '${new-name}' WHERE host_name = '${old-name}';
UPDATE ambari.hoststate set host_name = '${new-name}' WHERE host_name = '${old-name}';
UPDATE ambari.hosts set host_name = '${new-name}' WHERE host_name = '${old-name}';
COMMIT;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

If you're on postgresql:

```
ALTER TABLE ambari.clusterhostmapping DROP CONSTRAINT clusterhostmapping_cluster_id;
ALTER TABLE ambari.configgrouphostmapping DROP CONSTRAINT fk_cghm_hname;
ALTER TABLE ambari.host_role_command DROP CONSTRAINT fk_host_role_command_host_name;
ALTER TABLE ambari.hostcomponentdesiredstate DROP CONSTRAINT hstcmponentdesiredstatehstname;
ALTER TABLE ambari.hostcomponentstate DROP CONSTRAINT hostcomponentstate_host_name;
ALTER TABLE ambari.hostconfigmapping DROP CONSTRAINT fk_hostconfmapping_host_name;
ALTER TABLE ambari.hoststate DROP CONSTRAINT fk_hoststate_host_name;


BEGIN;
UPDATE ambari.clusterhostmapping set host_name = '${new-name}' WHERE host_name = '${old-name}';
UPDATE ambari.configgrouphostmapping set host_name = '${new-name}' WHERE host_name = '${old-name}';
UPDATE ambari.host_role_command set host_name = '${new-name}' WHERE host_name = '${old-name}';
UPDATE ambari.hostcomponentdesiredstate set host_name = '${new-name}' WHERE host_name = '${old-name}';
UPDATE ambari.hostcomponentstate set host_name = '${new-name}' WHERE host_name = '${old-name}';
UPDATE ambari.hostconfigmapping set host_name = '${new-name}' WHERE host_name = '${old-name}';
UPDATE ambari.hoststate set host_name = '${new-name}' WHERE host_name = '${old-name}';
UPDATE ambari.hosts set host_name = '${new-name}' WHERE host_name = '${old-name}';
COMMIT;


ALTER TABLE ambari.hoststate ADD CONSTRAINT fk_hoststate_host_name FOREIGN KEY (host_name) REFERENCES ambari.hosts(host_name);
ALTER TABLE ambari.hostconfigmapping ADD CONSTRAINT fk_hostconfmapping_host_name FOREIGN KEY (host_name) REFERENCES ambari.hosts(host_name);
ALTER TABLE ambari.hostcomponentstate ADD CONSTRAINT hostcomponentstate_host_name FOREIGN KEY (host_name) REFERENCES ambari.hosts(host_name);
ALTER TABLE ambari.hostcomponentdesiredstate ADD CONSTRAINT hstcmponentdesiredstatehstname FOREIGN KEY (host_name) REFERENCES ambari.hosts(host_name);
ALTER TABLE ambari.host_role_command ADD CONSTRAINT fk_host_role_command_host_name FOREIGN KEY (host_name) REFERENCES ambari.hosts(host_name);
ALTER TABLE ambari.configgrouphostmapping ADD CONSTRAINT fk_cghm_hname FOREIGN KEY (host_name) REFERENCES ambari.hosts(host_name);
ALTER TABLE ambari.clusterhostmapping ADD CONSTRAINT clusterhostmapping_cluster_id FOREIGN KEY (host_name) REFERENCES ambari.hosts(host_name);
```